# cakephp named parameter ignoring after last "." string

Tags: cakephp

```
http://www.example.com:8091/mails/compose/recipient:abc.xyz@gmail.com
```

When I am trying to get named parameter by using:

```php
$this->params['named']['recipient']
```

... it's ignoring everything after last `.`, it only shows `abc.xyz@gmail`.

Comment: I assume you are using Cake2.x? You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your named params.

But for those and a few other reasons it is advised to not use named params in 2.x anymore (they are a faulty implementation by design).
Instead use the properly working query strings from here on.

For details see [this article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/).